# object is not iterable when populate form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to populate the choices of a select field.

I am trying this code but I am receiving:

```
TypeError: 'Industry' object is not iterable
```

---

view

```
form = Filter_companies(request.form)

interests = Industry.query.all()
#[<app.companies.models.Industry object at 0xa9afc0c>, <app.companies.models.Industry object at 0xa9afc4c>}

form.industry.choices = interests
```

---

form

```
class Filter_companies(Form):
    industry = SelectField('Industry')
```

What is the reason of the error?

EDIT: something like this will populate with the representation of each object literally.

```
form.industry.choices = [(x, x) for x in interests]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choices` needs to be an interable containing key-value pairs.

```
interests = Industry.query.all()
form.industry.choices = [(interest.id, str(interest)) for interest in interests]
```

This will result in options where the `value` matches the `id` and the text matches the return value of `__str__`.

```
<option value="1">Name 1<option>
<option value="2">Name 2<option>
```

Comment: this will populate with the representation of each object literally. Not the values.

Comment: That means you haven't defined `Interest.__str__`. If you don't want to do that, you can use any attribute of `Interest` that you want. Without seeing its definition I can't use a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

you should populate a dict

```
form = Filter_companies(request.form)
interests = {}
industrydata = form.industry.choices
interests.append(andustry.query.all())
industrydata = interests.key('Industry')
print industrydata
```

without having much more info or additional info on how this data set is being generated this is what i think you should be looking at doing.